# Extracting Lats and Lons from grib2 file

Tags: python, matplotlib, wgrib2

I am working on NCEP GFS data to plot certain parameters. I use python for plotting and wgrib2 for extracting data from grib2 files. There are no problem as such to extract parameter from grib2 data (and converting in to numpy arry). However, I need to get Lats and Lons also so as to plot using matplotlib library. The command line option to know grid (lats and lons) information does not seems to produce what is required i.e lat 90.0 to -90.0 with an interval of 0.5. I used this command to extract lats/lons data:-

```
wgrib2 -grid -d 1 ../GRIB_DATA/gfs_p50_grib_data/gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p50.f000 -text -
```

and I received this data on terminal:-

```
-4.6
-4.6
-4.6
-4.6
-4.6
-4.5
-4.5
-4.5
-4.5
-4.5
-4.4
-4.4
-4.4
-4.4
-4.4
-4.3
-4.3
-4.3
-4.3
-4.2
-4.2
-4.2
-4.2
-4.1
-4.1
-4.1
-4.1
-4
-4
-4
-4
-3.9
-3.9
-3.9
-3.8
-3.8
-3.8
-3.7
-3.7
-3.7
-3.7
-3.6
-3.6
-3.6
-3.5
-3.5
-3.5
-3.4
-3.4
```

Can some one help me to guide in extracting lats and lons from grib2 data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeh, I found it. Here is the answer:-

```
wgrib2 -grid -d 1 ../GRIB_DATA/gfs_p50_grib_data/gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p50.f006 -spread -
```

Instead of writing output as text I redirected as spread and it produced this output (only few line are posted here) which I can manipulate later:-

```
354.000000,90.000000,3.7
354.500000,90.000000,3.6
355.000000,90.000000,3.6
355.500000,90.000000,3.6
356.000000,90.000000,3.6
356.500000,90.000000,3.6
357.000000,90.000000,3.6
357.500000,90.000000,3.6
358.000000,90.000000,3.6
358.500000,90.000000,3.5
359.000000,90.000000,3.5
359.500000,90.000000,3.5
```